# Uploadify - Random ID returned to form issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I have the following code which is supposed to return a random string back to the form once a file is uploaded. Previously to adding the `onUploadSuccess` code, it was working OK, but if I tried to upload multiple files, each file would have the same ID. I fixed this using the PHP to generate the random ID, but now I'm having issues getting the form to update.

The ID I'm trying to update is "data", but when I upload the files, I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'call'` error.

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated. If you need more info, let me know.

The Javascript:

```
<script>
        var sessid = ''; 
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#myModal').modal({show: false});
            $('#mm').modal({show: false});

                $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                    'fileObjName': 'file',
                    'fileSizeLimit': '8MB',
                    'buttonText': 'BROWSE FILE(S)...',
                    'fileTypeExts': '*.JPEG; *.GIF; *.PNG; *.APNG; *.TIFF; *.BMP; *.PDF; *.XCF',
                    'cancelImg': 'uploadify-cancel.png',
                    'swf': 'uploadify.swf',
                    'uploader': 'uploadify.php',
                    'auto': false,
                    'onUploadSuccess': $("data").livequery(function(file, data, response){
                            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=data;
                    })
                });
          });
    </script>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
if ( is_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {

$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
$randName = substr(sha1_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']), rand(0,30), 7);
$targetFile = 'uploads/'.$randName.'.' . $fileParts['extension'];

move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
echo $randName;
} else {
echo 'Malformed data';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you need to supply the function **definition** to the "onUploadSuccess" option; get rid of the **$("data").livequery( )**.

Use:

```
'onUploadSuccess': function(file, data, response){ 
                            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=data; 
                    }
```